# Can't access custom methods and any newly added file with AJAX in Opencart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess, opencart

I have a custom function that calls product file in controller via AJAX.
The problem is when the AJAX function is called, it is showing Network error: 404 http://localhost/opencart/index.php?route=product/product/checkzipcode was not found in the Firebug console and nothing is happening at all.

The AJAX function is fetching URL instead of method I think.

I have double-checked the URL and the function in the file. Both are correct and there. I have also added a new jQuery file in the header and again the same error is coming that the file not present:

> Network Error: 404.

I think there is an issue with my .htaccess file or php.ini file because errors are same with two different things.

How do I get access to the file on my host via AJAX?

Comment: What's the content of .htaccess?
Do you have a <base href="..." > tag in your html header?

Comment: @zeachco - The problem was resolved by myself. I had to refresh the modifications in admin to get the code running as refreshing modifications makes a duplicate of the method in the controller file in the modifications directory.